# I find the Register button using xpath but it's showing 2 matching nodes . How to uniquely identify the register button

Tags: java, selenium

Snap of the DOM here two matching nodes displayed for XPATH :

```
.//*[@id='header']/div/div[2]/div/a[2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath - `//div[@id='header'][not(@class)]//div[@class='right-side']/div/a[contains(.,'Register')]`

There are two almost same div containers. Only difference is that the relevant container does not have a class attribute, so the `not` part.

Or you can use xpath with index - `(//div[@class='right-side']/div/a[contains(.,'Register')])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

No need to find unique identifier for this, you can use find elements and click by index.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div/div[2]/div/a[2]")).get(index).click();
```

OR

You can use CSS Selector and locate the relevant element by using :nth-child(index).
In your case:

```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#header:nth-child(index) a.button.border:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

There are more different ways to locate the element using css selectors and I suggest to read about.
And when you inspect the element using the browser you can choose copy css or xpath, this option will give you the unique locator.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution (//[@id='header']/div/div[2]/div/a[2])[1] for the first one or (//[@id='header']/div/div[2]/div/a[2])[2] for the second one. But really you should practice writing more relative xpaths and not just taking what the plugins give you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for the complicated xpaths

---

This would work fine: `By.xpath("(//A[@href='/Account/Register'])[1]")`

I hope the below code helps you.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Upmile {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.get("http://upamile.com");
       //This website shows a dialog box at first 
       //we can skip that dialog by clicking on the body
       driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//A[@href='/Account/Register'])[1]")).click();
       System.out.println("Test ran successfully");
    }

 }
```